# Updating Angular and NPM Packages

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npx

Currently doing an upgrade from Angular 6 to 10 plus some other dependencies.

I follow this page using Angular CLI: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=7.0-8.0

But this seems to take forever, since the peer dependencies won't be handled automatically and I keep running into errors regarding unmet peer dependencies.

For example I get an error the dependency *"angular-user-idle"* has a peer dependency to **Angular 6** but finds **Angular 7**.

So I manually do need to research on Github, which version of *"angular-user-idle"* has Angular 7 in the peer depencies section in the `package.json`?

There has to be an easier way right, or can I just use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` flags to ignore everything and worry about peer dependencies once I am at Angular 10 version?